# What does "points of friction" mean in this sentence?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does "points of friction" mean in this sentence?

> Q: Are any of the **points of friction** which you read about in the Introduction & The Origins of the Cold War: U.S. Choices After WW2 mentioned in any of these sources? what are they? which sources mention them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant definition of "friction" is here:
[American Heritage Dictionary (2)](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=friction)

2. Conflict, as between persons having dissimilar ideas or interests; clash.

"Points of friction" means individual instances or examples of such conflict.